# Leaky abstraction in LINQ to SQL EntitySet

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I’m having trouble with some dbml generated classes that don’t to resolve down to efficient SQL.  Imagine I have an Accounts table and a Transactions table where each transaction is associated with a particular account.  I load all this into dbml and out pops an Account class and a Transaction class.  The Account class has an EntitySet reference to a collection of Transactions that represents all  the transactions on that account.  Fair enough.

Now suppose I only want the transactions for the current accounting period.  So I add a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Transaction> CurrentTransactions
{
    get
    {
        DateTime dtStart = CurrentPeriod;
        DateTime dtEnd = NextPeriod;
        return
            from t in Transactions
            orderby t.date
            where t.date >= CurrentPeriod && t.date <= NextPeriod
            select t;
    }
}
```

Looks nice and it works, but the SQL is not good:

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[account_id], [t0].[date], [t0].[description], [t0].[amount], [t0].[sign]
FROM [dbo].[transactions] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[account_id] = @p0
```

Ie: it’s pulling the entire set of transactions down and processing it with LINQ for Objects.  I’ve tried taking out the where clause, the orderby clause, replacing the dates with constants it’s all still done client side.

For comparison, I tried calling the Transactions collection directly off the data context:

```
DateTime dtStart = account.CurrentPeriod;
DateTime dtEnd = account.NextPeriod;
IEnumerable<Transaction> trans=
                from t in MyDataContext.Transactions
                orderby t.date
                where t.date >= dtStart && t.date <= dtEnd && t.account_id==iAccountID
                select t;
```

and it works beautifully:

```
SELECT [t0].[id], [t0].[account_id], [t0].[date], [t0].[description], [t0].[amount], [t0].[sign]
FROM [dbo].[transactions] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[date] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[date] <= @p1) AND ([t0].[account_id] = @p2)
ORDER BY [t0].[date]
```

So after all that, I have two questions:

1. Is the above behaviour of the Transactions EntitySet correct and/or is there a way to fix it?
2. How do I implement the above "fix" as a method on my Account class.  Entity classes generated by dbml don't have access to a DataContext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just cannot do that, sadly. Collection properties generated for LINQ to SQL entity classes are not `IQueryable`; therefore, any queries performed on them will be using LINQ to Objects. This is by design. As you rightly note yourself, to get efficient query you have to query over `Transactions` taken from your `DataContext`, but you don't have one in your property gettor.

At this point your options are either:

- Make it a method which takes a `DataContext` as argument; or
- Use reflection hackery to retrive the context - entity itself doesn't store it, but `EntitySet`s on it do, albeit indirectly - naturally this is version specific, prone to breakage, etc.

So far as I know, Entity Framework does not have this limitation, since its collection properties are `ObjectQuery<T>` - which is `IQueryable`.

Comment: Collection properties of Entity Framework, at least from 2009 until now, are not of type `ObjectQuery<T>` but of type `EntityCollection<T>` (which, however, has a method to transform them into an `ObjectQuery<T>`).

Answer (score 3):

What is the type of *Transactions* in the first example?

Remember you are using Extension Methods. The Linq Extension Methods that are used are dependant on the interface *Transactions* implements:

- IQueryable<T> would be linq-to-sql or linq-to-entities or ...
- IEnumerable<T> will give you linq-to-objects.

Edit:

This is the fingerprint of the EntitySet type:

```
public sealed class EntitySet<TEntity> : IList, 
    ICollection, IList<TEntity>, ICollection<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, 
    IEnumerable, IListSource
where TEntity : class
```

To answer your questions:

1. *Transactions* does not implement IQueryable<T> so it is the correct behaviour
2. Your account class will need to be able to reference the Transactions Table object

Comment: Transactions is the dbml generated EntitySet property.    

[Association(Name="Account_Transaction", Storage="_Transactions", ThisKey="id", OtherKey="account_id")]
  public EntitySet<Transaction> Transactions

Comment: Regarding 2).  I understand this, the problem is how do I get such a reference given that the Account objects are typically created by the data context/entity framework?  Where would I hook in to pass the account object a reference to the transactions table?  Or, put another way, given an entity object that is associated with a particular data context, how do I get from that entity back to it's data context?

Comment: You are extending the functionality of the Account object right? Add a parameterized method call? IEnumerable<Transaction> GetCurrentTransactions(DataContext ctx)

Comment: I am assuming the Account object is defined as a partial class, or you could create an Extension Method.

Comment: Yes Account object is a partial class.  Passing the dc to the method is OK I suppose except I'm using the Account object as the type for strongly typed MVC view where I don't currently have the dc available.  

Thinking about this more, I think I'll rearrange it all and use a new object for the MVC view and pull the transactions directly from the dc - rather than via the account.  

Still I'm surprised that the dbml generated classes leak so easily - I would presume what I was attempting is a fairly standard sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from using IEnumerable throughout to IQueryable instead and your SQL will be optimized to only pull on demand what you need.

Comment: It won't. His problem is that `Transactions` is not `IQueryable`, and he cannot do anything about it (it is an `EntitySet`, and must remain one).

Comment: Yep that's exactly the problem.

Comment: Argh.  Never an easy solution. :)